# How to send multiple files with Response. ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to call below code in a loop hundreds of times:

```
   Sub ExportReport(ByVal en As MyReport)
        Dim warnings As Warning() = Nothing
        Dim streamids As String() = Nothing
        Dim mimeType As String = Nothing
        Dim encoding As String = Nothing
        Dim extension As String = Nothing
        Dim bytes As Byte()
            bytes = aReport.ServerReport.Render("WORD", Nothing, mimeType, encoding, extension, streamids, warnings)


        Response.Buffer = True
        Response.Clear()
        Response.ContentType = mimeType
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" & en.ToString() & "." + extension)
        Response.BinaryWrite(bytes)
        Response.Flush()
        Response.End()

    End Sub
```

And I'm getting this error :

> Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent.

How can I change the code so that I can loop this piece of code? Thanks.

EDIT : 
I added this line after `Response.End()`

```
Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri)
```

And I get this error :

> Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent.

Comment: You create "hundreds" of reports to send them as download-stream? The browser will support only one file per request...

Comment: @OlafWatteroth In fact, the browser doesn't even allow the download of the first file. The first download fails as well. Do you have anything to suggest. I will run this code only once and download the files and it will be ok.

Comment: Could you maybe post some more code? From your snippet it all looks pretty fine for a file download.

Comment: Is this from an aspx page (bad) or some handler like an ashx handler (good)?

Comment: @AndrewMorton I don't feel it's good but it is from `UserControl`.

Comment: @jason What causes the download to happen - does the user click on a link?

Comment: @AndrewMorton `btn_click`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

WWW works on a request / response mechanism. For every request there is only 1 response. You cannot change that basic mechanism. When browser sends a request it is expecting one and only one response. So if it receives more than 1 response, it either issues a warning to the user to block this behaviour or may choose to ignore the extra responses by itself. Thus these extra responses may be lost.

Having said that you have 2 options with you:

1. Zip all the files that you want to download and download as a single file.

You can use Popular framework [Ionic.Zip](https://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/).

First, keep all your files in a local directory on the server.
Then use this library to zip the entire folder.

Pseudo code:

```
Imports (var zip = New Ionic.Zip.ZipFile())
{
   zip.AddDirectory("DirectoryOnDisk", "rootInZipFile")
   Response.Clear()
   Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=DownloadedFile.zip")
   Response.ContentType = "application/zip"
   zip.Save(Response.OutputStream)
   Response.End()
}
```

2. Add a mechanism to issue multiple request using Javascript to get multiple responses, so browser still treats this behaviour as normal.

Comment: Could you give me some hints about making it as a ZIP file?

Comment: Like how I should change my code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Added more details

Comment: Good suggestion. Works

Answer (score 0):

A normal web page will have a load of (headers) stuff set up for you already, but you don't want any of that: you want complete control over what is sent to the browser. If you cause a redirect to something which sends the headers shown in code later here, the browser will (normally) download the data.

In the code-behind you can have something like

```
Protected Sub btn_click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btn.Click
    Response.Redirect("~/sendfile.ashx?ref=" & enReference, False)
    Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()

End Sub
```

You will also need to add a generic handler (right-click on the project in Solution Explorer, Add->New Item... -> Visual Basic--Web--General choose "Generic Handler"; give it a name like sendfile.ashx) which is somewhat like

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class sendfile
    Implements System.Web.IHttpHandler, IReadOnlySessionState

    Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest

        Dim enReference = context.Request.QueryString("ref")
        ' do whatever is needed to get the report from enReference '
        Dim bytes As Byte() = aReport.ServerReport.Render("WORD", Nothing, mimeType, encoding, extension, streamids, warnings)
        Dim downloadName = yourfilename & "." & yourextension

        context.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
        context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=""" & downloadName & """"  )
        context.Response.BinaryWrite(bytes)

    End Sub

    ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable
        Get
            Return False
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

and you will need to work out the code to create the data to be sent.

If you don't need to use session state then you can remove the `, IReadOnlySessionState` part on the `Implements` line.

You *might* need to add `context.Response.Flush()`. If you find that the response does not have a Content-Length header, then you ought to add one so that the browser can show a meaningful download progress.